# Sorting by DATE and TIME using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort the objects by Date and Time -> for example if the dates and times are: **24/04/2015 14:00** & **24/04/2015 09:00** & **25/04/2015 15:00** order should be this:

1. 24/04/2015 09:00
2. 24/04/2015 14:00
3. 25/04/2015 15:00

In my case the order is this:

1. 24/04/2015 14:00
2. 24/04/2015 09:00
3. 25/04/2015 15:00

It gets sorted by date, but ignores the time.

**The code**

```
        Collections.sort(myObjects, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
            @Override 
            public int compare(MyObject object1, MyObject object2) {
                return object1.getDate().compareTo(object2.getDate());
            }
        });
```

**P.S.** getDate() method of myObject class is a regular getter which simply returns a java.util.Date object.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

The Date was coming from MySQL DB, datatype is DATE, therefore it was loosing the exact time and the TIME was ignored during sorting. That is also a reason why I was not able to reproduce the problem, as I was always setting the Date objects manually considering the time.

Comment: what concrete date class do you use?

Comment: This should work as is, could you provide a reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: you should provide a reproducable example... my guess is that you have either a bug in your getDate() method or you are just looking at the wrong list...

Comment: Pshemo: edited, casting was necessary as I was doing time complementers explicitly, which is of type long

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it here, lots of code involved.

Comment: Please post [simple but complete example which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). Without that we can only guess what went wrong and not everyone likes guessing games when they could spent their time on questions which have easier to reproduce and debug problems...

Comment: You are right. As it is I am not able to reproduce the problem as its to much code involved, trying to make it reasonably shorter flashes the problem. Therefore I know that posted piece should work as is, and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Since you agree that your question has no point because problem is placed somewhere else where we don't have access, consider deleting this question and reposting new one when you will be able to create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried following code and its sorting correctly. May be you can compare and find out if you have any issues the way you are populating the date object

```
public class DateSorter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(2015, 4, 24, 14, 00);
    Date dt1 = cal.getTime();

    cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(2015, 4, 24, 9, 00);
    Date dt2 = cal.getTime();

    cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(2015, 4, 25, 15, 00);
    Date dt3 = cal.getTime();

    myObjects.add(new MyObject("1", dt1));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject("2", dt2));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject("3", dt3));

    Collections.sort(myObjects, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObject object1, MyObject object2) {
            return (int) (object1.getDate().compareTo(object2.getDate()));
        }
    });

    System.out.println(myObjects.get(0));
    System.out.println(myObjects.get(1));
    System.out.println(myObjects.get(2));

}

}
```

Comment: See update, yes populating the Date objects was the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare by milliseconds value of date. (getTime() method).

Comment: date class's compareTo  method use time in millis

Comment: Right, but in getting milliseconds when comparing date and when getting time there is a bit diffrent flow. Anyway comparing milliseconds may give some good idea about the problem, maybe dates created in some special way

Comment: check this implementation of compareTo in date class public int compareTo(Date anotherDate) {
        long thisTime = getMillisOf(this);
        long anotherTime = getMillisOf(anotherDate);
        return (thisTime<anotherTime ? -1 : (thisTime==anotherTime ? 0 : 1));
    }